# Debian with kernel above 5.4

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

My new laptop (dell g5 5505 s Amd ryzen 5 with Radeon graphics) doesn't support linux os with old kernel, how and where can I download debian with latest kernel. And my laptop has a gaming key and it doesn't work with ubuntu live, how could I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Install the kernel from Buster backports:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free" |\
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -t buster-backports install linux-image-amd64
sudo reboot
```

[Debian wiki: AtiHowTo](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo)

Comment: Laptop doesn't allow me to boot the installer with kernel 4.9

Comment: @HR20dev Disable the secure boot.

Comment: Secure boot is disabled , still I recieve this problem